# How to access boolean variable from one component inside app component - Angular

Tags: angular, boolean, components, hide, show

I have a scenario wherein i have multiple pages for which there is back arrow icon at application level across all forms.
I am trying to set the back arrow in app.component.html as its common across all the forms. But some of the forms doesnt have back arrow. I need to hide back arrow only for those forms.
In order to hide the back arrow for some forms(for eg., otp.component.ts), I have tried to match the url string name, and hide the back arrow if user reaches that specific form. This i am doing inside app.component. This doesnt work as the app component loads only once on load of the application.Is there any way to achieve this scenario.

May be I need to match the string logic inside otp.component.ts and pass the boolean value to app.component.html. But I am not sure how to achieve this.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
app.component.html :

 <button class="header_back" *ngIf="showBackIcon" (click)="goBack()"></button>
    <button class="header_close" *ngIf="showCloseIcon" (click)="close()"></button>

app.component.ts:
 constructor() {
    const urlPath = window.location.href; 
    if (urlPath.indexOf("/otp") > -1) {
      this.showCloseIcon=true;
      this.showBackIcon=false;
    } else {
      this.showCloseIcon=false;
      this.showBackIcon=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can make this button a child component and use it where ever you require it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an injected service that carries out the path checking logic and assigns to a property within the service.

That can then be accessed throughout the application by injecting in constructor so you can call it from other components and  read the updated value in app.component e.g. this.backArrowService.showBackIcon

new service back-arrow.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class BackArrowService {
public showBackIcon: boolean;
//etc
```

Any component:

```
import { BackArrowService } from './back-arrow.service.ts';
...
constructor(public backService: BackArrowService ) {}

/*Example of directly updating value of service property which can be accessed 
from other components that inject the service also*/
...
ngOnInit() {
this.backService.showBackIcon = true;
}
```

App component html:

```
//See the value change:
{{backService.showBackIcon}}

<button class="header_back" *ngIf="backService.showBackIcon" (click)="goBack()"></button>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with an example? Should that service be app.service.ts or where should that service be created

Comment: A new service which you can create wherever you like. Look up how to generate service for Angular. this way, the functions and properties are shared / accessible between components I've added more details to answer.

Comment: But my arrow icon and the state of boolean is maintained in app.html file . How to update the state of this variable through service.

Comment: Maintain the state of the boolean in the service instead using the new property in the service. Then access this from your app component html e.g. {{backService.showCloseIcon}}. you can update this property from any component.ts file that you inject the service in and read it from any component. You can also create a function in the service and call it from any component with e.g. this.backService.myFunction() which could update the value of the boolean within the service.

Comment: Have added further example to answer.

Comment: But the concern here is app.component as the button is added in app.component and when i load /otp screen, my verify.component get loaded and how to pass the state of showBackIcon from service to app.component because the app.component is loaded only once.

Comment: The value will update automatically in app.component if it is updated from the components within app component as long as they are using the same variable in the service. The app component will have the same service injected and so will be updated with the latest value of the property when the property is updated in a child component. Try doing a simple update of the property from a child component and seeing that the value updates in your app html.